# Does fprintf() in c prints output to a file one by one or in bulk?

Tags: c, sh

I am using this code to print my output in a file

```
FILE * file;
file = fopen("output.txt", "a");
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

    loop(arr, a_d, Y_d, sample_d, A_d, y_d, res_d, res,x_d, R_d, A1_d, y1_d, Q_d, TAU_d, devInfo, m, n, i);

    float s = minimum(arr, 7802);

    fprintf(file,"%f\n", s);
}

fclose(file);
```

But I need to get the number of lines filled in output.txt file by -wc command in a shell script for printing the progress of program in percentage. 
I don't know if fprinf() prints output one by one to a file or in last. So, can anyone suggest me to some alternative way to do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong thing, but let me explain:

`(f)printf()` outputs to a `stdio` *stream*, and those streams can be either unbuffered or buffered in two different modes: *fully* buffered or *line* buffered.

A `FILE *` stream opened with `fopen()` will typically be in full buffered mode. This means output only occurs when the buffer is full or when the stream is flushed (`fflush()` or implicitly when you close it).

You can change the buffering mode with [`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) or you can just call [`fflush()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) after each output.

---

As for what you want to achieve, I think it would be better to emit progress information directly from your program. You could for example use `stderr` for this.

Comment: Can you explain more how do I get progress information from my program directly??

Comment: Not really, this depends on what you need. You could for example calculate a percent value after each step und just `fprintf()` it to `stderr` ...

Comment: I just want to show my progress in percentage. Can you show me an example of how to do it??